# Node + Express - Getting dbData before the render

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I am trying to render a view with a table of data fetched from a local db. The query and all data checks out in the format I want. But before the data is fetched, the view is rendered, and i get an error.

This is my route.js where I would expect the error to be found.

```
exports.getIndex = (req, res) {
  const result = sqldb.GetSubscribers()
  try{
      res.render('subscribtions/index', {
        moment: moment,
        subs : result,
        pageTitle: 'Subscribtions',
        path: '/subscribtions'
        })
      }
  catch(error)
      {
        console.log(error)
        res.redirect(404, '../views/404.ejs');
      }
};
```

DBcall just for orientation

```
exports.GetSubscribers = function() {
    const connString = "ConnectionString";

    query = "Some Long Query" 

    sql.open(connString, (err, con) => {
        if (err) {
        console.log('failed to open ' + err.message)
        }
        con.prepare(query, (err, ps) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Fejl - prepare: '+err.message)
                return
            }
            con.query(query, (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Fejl - query: '+ err.message)
                    return err;
                }
                console.log("Returning results...")
                return rows;
            })
        })
    })
}
```

So far I have been trying to work out how to use async/await or Promise, but without any luck. 
Can any of you brilliant minds point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably that the db call is async and since you don't await it it will return the rendered view before the data has been fully fetched.

Thus you need to await the call to the database. Given that the function is awaitable:

```
exports.getIndex = async (req, res) => {
  ...
  try {
     const result = await sqldb.GetSubscribers();
  }
  catch(err) {
     console.log('Error getting subscribers', err);
  }
  ...
};
```

Alternatively, if the function is then-able:

```
exports.getIndex = (req, res) => {
  return sqldb.GetSubscribers().then(result => 
    res.render('subscribtions/index', {
      moment: moment,
      subs : result,
      pageTitle: 'Subscribtions',
      path: '/subscribtions'
    })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    res.redirect(404, '../views/404.ejs');
  }));
}
```

To make the `GetSubscribers`function return a promise:

```
exports.GetSubscribers = () => {
  const connString = 'ConnectionString';

  query = 'Some Long Query';

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sql.open(connString, (err, con) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`failed to open ${err.message}`);
      }
      con.prepare(query, (err, ps) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`Fejl - prepare: ${err.message}`);
          reject();
        }
        con.query(query, (err, rows) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(`Fejl - query: ${err.message}`);
            reject(err);
          }
          console.log('Returning results...');
          resolve(rows);
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Hello Christian, thx for the reply. Sadly it still doesn't wait on the data.
I have added the dbcall for reference

Comment: You need to make the GetSubscribers function either take a callback function which is invoked when the query is complete or create a promise which resolves when it's complete.

Comment: Getting closer. Im getting this errormsg

(node:18412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18412) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: So if you're using the `await` version, you need to wrap the call in a try catch block and log the error.

Comment: Thanks a million Christian for your patience. The issue has been resolved. Ha en bra dag